# React-Redux TypeError: this.props.getAnimals is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

When using react, redux and thunk to fetch some data from an API, I am experiencing an error

> TypeError: this.props.getAnimals is not a function\

which is triggered by the line

```
this.props.getAnimals();
```

Using Redux Tools, we can see that `this.props.getAnimals` function was successfully executed, showing the actions `animals_are_loading`, `get_animals` and `animals_are_loading` again, and the states are being updated correctly, as is what you will expect to see when `this.props.getAnimals()` has called the function `getAnimals`.

Any idea what is happening?

**containers/Animals.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getAnimals } from '../../actions';

class Animals extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getAnimals();
    }

    renderAnimalsList() {
        return ...
    }

    renderLoading() {
        return ...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Animals</h1>
                { (this.props.animalsAreLoading) ? this.renderLoading() : this.renderAnimalsList() }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        animals: state.animals.animals,
        animalsAreLoading: state.animals.isLoading
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getAnimals
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, getAnimals)(Animals)
```

**actions/index.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_ANIMALS_SUCCESS, ANIMALS_ARE_LOADING } from './types';

export function getAnimals() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch(animalsAreLoading(true))    // ACTION SEEN IN REDUX TOOLS
        axios
            .get(`${ROOT_URL}/animals`, {
                headers: {authorization: localStorage.getItem('token')}
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data.animals)    // THIS RETURNS DATA!
                // ACTION SEEN IN REDUX TOOLS
                dispatch(getAnimalsSuccess(response.data.animals)) 
                // ACTION SEEN IN REDUX TOOLS
                dispatch(animalsAreLoading(false))
                return response
            })
    }
}

export function animalsAreLoading(bool) {
    return {
        type: ANIMALS_ARE_LOADING,
        payload: bool
    }
}

export function getAnimalsSuccess(animals) {
    return {
        type: GET_ANIMALS_SUCCESS,
        payload: animals
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: just replace these line of codes with yours

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return ({
        getAnimals: () => dispatch(getAnimals())
    })
}
```

The error:

> TypeError: this.props.getAnimals is not a function

That's pretty clear! Because after merging the `return object` of the `mapDispatchToProps()` function to the `props` object of the React component. The `getAnimals` property is actually `not a function`.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getAnimals     // this property is properly not a function
    }
}
```

What I did to fix the error is setting the value to the `getAnimals` property:

```
getAnimals: () => dispatch(getAnimals())
```

make its value become a function which dispatches an action creator.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a simple `mapDispatchToProps` mistake:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, **getAnimals**)(Animals)
```

replace with:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Animals)
```

---

You can also inline `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` in the `connect` function:

```
export default connect(state => ({
  animals: state.animals.animals,
  animalsAreLoading: state.animals.isLoading 
}), { getAnimals })(Animals)
```